# The Eigenvalues of a Matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields

Consider $\bf A$ is a non-singular binary matrix over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Assume that the characteristic polynomial of $\bf A$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is ${\bf f}(x)^k$ for some $k$ where ${\bf f}(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Suppose that ${\bf g}(x)\neq {\bf f}(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Consider the matrix ${\bf B}={\bf g}({\bf A})$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. From linear algebra we know that ${\bf B}$ is not a zero matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$. But what can we say about singularity of the matrix ${\bf B}$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

**My question:** Is it true this claim that the matrix ${\bf B}$ is a non-singular matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

*My try:* Consider $\lambda_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$, are eigenvalues of the matrix $\bf A$. Becuse of the matrix $\bf A$ is a non-singular matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ we conclude that $\lambda_i$'s are non-zero. Moreover, 
from linear algebra we know that $\det({\bf B})=\prod_{i=1}^n{\bf g}(\lambda_i)$.
Therefore, if the matrix ${\bf B}$ be a singular matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ then there is at least an $\lambda_i$ for some $1\leq j \leq n$ such that ${\bf g}(\lambda_j)=0$ which means the matrix ${\bf B}$ has an eigenvalue equal to zero. I don't know how this issue helps to our discussion.

In fact, my problems is that how to obtain the eigenvalues of the  matrix $\bf A$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

I would very much appreciate any assistance you can offer me in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT. It's true because, in $F_2$ , $1$ is the only invertible.

The $(\lambda_i)$ are in an algebraic extension of $F_2$ and $f$ is their common unitary minimal polynomial. If $g(\lambda_j)=0$, then $g$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $\lambda_j$, that is $g=f$.

Answer 1 to @user0410. The minimal polynomial of $\lambda\in K$ over $F_2$, ($K$ an algebraic extension of $F_2$) is $h$, the unitary polynomial of minimal degree ($>0$) among the polynomials that admit $\lambda$ as a root. One can prove that $h$ is irreducible and, conversely, if a unitary irreducible polynomial admits $\lambda$ as a root, then it 's $h$. Here $f$ is the minimal polynomial of all its roots (the $(\lambda_i)$'s).

Answer 2 to @user0410. Your polynomial $f=x^4+x+1$ decomposes in $K$, an algebraic extension of degree $4$; $g=x^6+x+1$ factorizes in $K$ in the form $g=p(x)q(x)$ where $degree(p)=degree(q)=3$. Yet $g$ decomposes in $L\supset K$. Of course, $g(A)$ is invertible and I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is it possible to ask you to explain more or make an example. I can not understand the concept of this expression *common unitary minimal polynomial*

Comment: I wanted to say that if $\alpha^{2^i}$ for $0\leq i \leq 3$ be root of $\bf f$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ and 
 $\bf g(A)$ be a singular matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ then at least there is an $0\leq i \leq 3$ such that ${\bf g}(\alpha^{2^i})=0$ and this results in $\bf g$ must be a power of $\bf f$ and this is contradiction to  irreducibility of $\bf g$. Is it true discussion? Thanks  for your editions.

Comment: I point out that any irreducible polynomial $P$ behaves like your particular $ f $, that is, if $\beta$ is a root of $P$, then the other roots are $\beta^2,\beta^4,\beta^8,\cdots$; in other words, the Galois group of $P$ is cyclic. It is for this reason that, $L$, the decomposition field of your $g$ is an algebric extension of degree $3$ of $K$. About your comment, you are right but I don't see the interest. As Berci wrote, it is well-known that two non-proportional irreducible polynomials have no common roots.

Comment: I got it thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ live in an *extension* of $\Bbb F_2$, namely in $\Bbb F_2[x]/(f)$ which is the finite field of size $2^{\deg f}$.

Since $f$ and $g$ are distinct irreducible polynomials, $\gcd(f, g)=1$, so they don't share a root even in a field extension.

It proves $g(\lambda_i)\ne0$, hence $\det B\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it possible to reference for this expression in your answer that *Since $f$ and $g$ are distinct irreducible polynomials, $\gcd(f, g)=1$, so they don't share a root even in a field extension.* In fact, is it true to say  if $\bf g$ has a common root with $\bf f$ then $\bf g$ should be a power of $\bf f$ and this is contradicts to irreducibility of $\bf g$.

Comment: No, $g$ is a *multiple* of $f$ then.